# Issue with RecyclerView not updating when returning to the first page after navigating to the second page of ViewPager2

Tags: android-viewpager

My code is a program that displays ViewPager2 in the MainActivity and shows different lists on the second page using RecyclerView. When I press the Edit mode, the checkboxes and move buttons of each item in the RecyclerView should be displayed. Initially, when I launch the app, the Edit mode works correctly on both the first and second pages of the ViewPager. However, when I navigate to the second page and return to the first page, the RecyclerView is not immediately updated; only the items that are scrolled out and then back into view are updated. If I go back to the second page again, the second page works correctly. It seems that the first page, once loaded, is not being updated. Is there any way to resolve this issue?

Video: https://youtube.com/shorts/adKN6vzZeRo

"I want the Edit mode to work correctly when returning to the first page. How can I achieve this?

Main activity :

```
wordViewPagerAdapter.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

recycler view :

```
fun bind() {
        if (mainRecyclerViewListener.isEditMode()) {
            checkBox.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            orderChange.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            duplicateCount.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        } else {
            checkBox.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            orderChange.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            duplicateCount.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        }
        //취소선 추가
        if (isSecondPage) {
            textView.paintFlags = textView.paintFlags or Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://youtube.com/shorts/ofEv3fu-Mv4?feature=share3